# Report tool with cells merging

Tags: delphi, merge, report, cells

Are there any reporting tools for Delphi that allow cells merging vertically (like Excel does)?
For example, as far as I know, popular reporting tool FastReport doesn't allow such merging in a simple way.

Answer (score 2):

There's a property called SuppressRepeated on TfrxMemoView that could be used to visually emulate merge cells.

Comment: I know about SuppressRepeated property, but it doesn't give what I'd like to get. When I try to set cells merging up, it ends up in dynamic hiding cell borders etc, and that's not what you want from cell merging.
That's why I ask about OTHER reporting tools - are there any suitable for doing this?